# return dynamic value in java REST / Spring / Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, rest, jboss

I've inherited a REST API that is using JBoss, Spring, Hibernate, etc. and I'm new to all these so please forgive what seems like a dumb question (to me).

The basic flow when performing a GET is to build an entity list add it to a ModelAndView object then return it.

**QUESTION:** 
How can I add a calculated value to a response?

I don't want to store calculated values in the database, nor do I want to add a member to each entity that is being returned (ie an `ArrayList<Athletes>` and add a "points behind the leader" member to the Athletes class).  I simply want to perform the calculation on for each request and append a member to the json response with that dynamic value like so:

```
{
"Athlete1" : {"name" : "bob", "someDynamicValue" : "124548412" }
}
```

Seems like this would be relatively common but I can't seem to find a simple solution.....maybe i'm just not sure how to ask the question correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS - I thought this would help me [Returning entities in Rest API with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739314/returning-entities-in-rest-api-with-spring) but the answer never addressed my questions, how to add dynamic values to the response.

EDIT: Per request here's some simplified code

```
public ModelAndView getAthletes(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
    throws WebServiceException {

        res.setContentType("text/xml");

        List<AthleteStat> athleteStats = athleteManager.getAthleteStats();


        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();


        model.put("athleteStats", athleteStats);

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("athletes.ftl", "model", model);
        modelAndView.setCacheable(true);

        return modelAndView;        

    } 



public class AthleteStat{

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String hometown;
        private String resides;
    private Date birthdate;

    //getters and setters

}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<#escape x as x?xml>
<response status="ok">
    <Data>      
        <Athletes>
        <#list model.athleteStats as athleteStat>
            <Athlete Name="${athleteStat.athlete.name}" InternalID="${athleteStat.athlete.id?c}">
                <AbbrevName><#if athleteStat.athlete.abbrevName?exists>${athleteStat.athlete.abbrevName}</#if></AbbrevName>
                <Birthdate><#if athleteStat.athlete.birthdate?exists>${athleteStat.athlete.birthdate?string("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")}</#if></Birthdate>
                <Hometown><#if athleteStat.athlete.hometown?exists>${athleteStat.athlete.hometown}</#if></Hometown>
                <Resides><#if athleteStat.athlete.resides?exists>${athleteStat.athlete.resides}</#if></Resides>
                <Age><#if athleteStat.athlete.age?exists>${athleteStat.athlete.age}</#if></Age>
            </Athlete>
        </#list>
        </Athletes>
    </Data>
</response>
</#escape>
```

Comment: Can you give a little of the code for `Athletes`? Also a controller method that returns it. Changing the serialization into JSON depends on how you are doing it right now.

Comment: @acdcjunior sure.  The getAtheletes() method builds a list of the simple AthleteStat objects and is passed into a ModelAndView object along with a athletes.ftl.  I'm trying to append a calculated value either in the getAtheletes method or the .ftl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put in the model an additional map which will map those dynamic values to each athlete.

Like this: Where you have

```
model.put("athleteStats", athleteStats);
```

Add the generation of the dynamic value map and add it to the model:

```
model.put("athleteStats", athleteStats);
Map<Integer, String> dynamicValues = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
for(AthleteStat athleteStat : athleteStats) {
   String dynValue = athleteStat.toString(); /* calculate the dynamic value */
   dynamicValues.put(athleteStat.getId(), dynValue);
}
model.put("dynamicValues", dynamicValues);
```

Now add this line to map it:

```
<Dynamic>
    <#if model.dynamicValues.get(athleteStat.athlete.id)?exists>
        ${model.dynamicValues.get(athleteStat.athlete.id)}
    </#if>
</Dynamic>
```

Like:

```
...
        <Age><#if athleteStat.athlete.age?exists>${athleteStat.athlete.age}</#if></Age>
        <Dynamic><#if model.dynamicValues.get(athleteStat.athlete.id)?exists>${model.dynamicValues.get(athleteStat.athlete.id)}</#if></Dynamic>
    </Athlete>
</#list>
```